# Tomcat 7 ssl client authenitcation

Tags: java, ssl, client-server, ssl-certificate, tomcat7

I want to make a webapp accessible to some limited users only. So I select a SSL client authentication. I am newbie so not much knowledge about it I follow [this tutorial](http://www.vorburger.ch/blog1/2006/08/setting-up-two-way-mutual-ssl-with.html) to achive it. here is some quires in my mind. I am using basic self signed SSL.

1) Can we create a single client certificate for all clients which is provide by me? so whoever has a client certificate can access a app. sounds not a good way.

2) if not (1) then is there easy way to create a client certificate and register on tomcat user.xml. I dont want to force user to create a client certificate and send me so I register on server.

3) How to redirect to some other page if SSL certificate not match.?

4) can we use a private public key of one machine to another one?

5) there is multiple apps on my server but I want to authenticate only one app with SSL. Is is possible then how?

please also suggest me any good tutorials for this.  Finally My requriment is to give access to limited users up to 50. and my clients can register his system in some user friendly way.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Can we create a single client certificate for all clients which is provide by me?

It doesn't make sense. The client certificate is supposed to uniquely identify the client. They should have one each.

> so whoever has a client certificate can access a app. sounds not a good way.

It isn't.

> 2) if not (1) then is there easy way to create a client certificate and register on tomcat user.xml. I dont want to force user to create a client certificate and send me so I register on server.

It's the only secure way. If you create the certificate you have the private key so it isn't private so it can't do what it's supposed to do, legally. For example you can't prove that only the client could have executed any transaction, so you lose legal non-repudiability. You shoudn't be using users.xml for this, you should be using one of the other Tomcat security Realms, for example a database.

> 3) How to redirect to some other page if SSL certificate not match.?

If you're using Container Managed Authentication, which you should be, that's all defined in web.xml for the application.

> 4) can we use a private public key of one machine to another one?

It doesn't make sense, see above. A private key is supposed to be private and under the exclusive control of one entity.

I question whether using client certificates is even the right solution here. If you just want to restrict access to the server give each client a login.

5) there is multiple apps on my server but I want to authenticate only one app with SS